# Spring security shows "bad credentials" error instead of redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

this is my spring-security.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/courses*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <custom-filter  before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="MyAuthFilter" />
        <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/courses"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="loginField"
            password-parameter="passwordField" />
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="ars" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

here is MyAuthFilter:

```
@Component("MyAuthFilter")
public class MyAuthFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        System.out.println("running my own version of UsernmePasswordFilter ... ");

        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
        loginForm.setUsername(request.getParameter("login"));
        loginForm.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
        request.setAttribute("error", 3);
        System.out.println("login : " + loginForm.getUsername());
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginForm.getUsername(), loginForm.getPassword());
        setDetails(request, authRequest);
        Authentication authResult = this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);

        return authResult;
    }
}
```

When i enter wrong login or password it shows "bad credentials" error instead of redirecting to a login page.Without custom filter it works fine.
I just want to check what wrong with login\password and set "error" wariable, wich i use in login form to show concrete error like " empty pass" etc.

I need to make a login page witch shows concrete error like "empty pass\empty login\ both empty\wrong login or pass". I will be very greatfull if someone could share a link with example or guide for those validation.

Answer (score 2):

Define success and failure handler

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler getSuccessHandler(){
  SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler =  new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
  handler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/login.html");
  return handler;
}


@Bean
public AuthenticationFailureHandler getFailureHandler(){
  SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler handler  =  new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
  handler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login.html");
  return handler;
}
```

in your filter

```
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        this.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
        this.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
    }
```

Comment: No qualifying bean of type AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

Comment: you need to define those beans as above

Comment: I did it as  above and it's show error
`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Comment: You have to put them into a config class. It looks like you have no clue how spring actually works and you should really take a look at spring boot getting started guides.